# Enable-Migrations: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I setup a EF 6.1.3 project.

When I run Enable-Migrations I get this exception:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
PM>
```

What is the problem with "contains no matching element".

I use Code first and there exist no database of course.

When I outcomment the code in the OnModelCreating:

I get NO Error. What is the problem with my Fluent setup of columns?

```
 public class TaaSContext : DbContext
    { 
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Translation> Translations { get; set; }

        public TaaSContext() : base("defaultConnectionString")
        {
            base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Database.SetInitializer(new TaaSContextInitializer());
        }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    // Application
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
        //        .Property(a => a.Name);

        //    // Language
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
        //        .Property(a => a.ISO639_ISO3166)
        //        .HasColumnType("char")
        //        .HasMaxLength(5)
        //        .IsRequired();

        //    // Translation
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
        //        .Property(a => a.Key)
        //        .IsRequired();

        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
        //        .Property(a => a.Text)
        //        .HasColumnType("string")
        //        .IsRequired();

        //    modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
        //        .Property(a => a.ISO639_ISO3166)
        //        .HasColumnType("char")
        //        .HasMaxLength(5)
        //        .IsRequired();

        //}
    }
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d599e76-36ea-406c-b33b-b06d78745b8f/ef-6-code-first-migration-sequence-contains-no-matching-element-erro?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Could you check the attributes on your Models? Sometimes an incorrect attribute will trigger this.

Comment: @Will I already deleted my Migrations folder. And did enable-migrations again and the error comes again.

Comment: HasColumnType("string") ? Shouldn't it be `nvarchar` or `varchar`  ?

Comment: damn... it seems that was it! too much in to C# :P